# Python: Xpath not able to locate element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get some data from a website but getting below error. It worked last night but when I rerun in today it is suddenly not able to locate the elements. Today, I tried almost I could but Couldn't resolve it.

Tools and Language - Python, Selenium, Chrome, Chromedriver, AWS Cloud 9, EC2

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


driver.get('https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/19496/scorecard/1198235/england-vs-australia-1st-t20i-england-v-australia-2020')
time.sleep(20)
element_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]').text
print(element_text)
```

Error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]"}
```

I tried below thing

1. Added and removed sleep time. Increased and decreased sleep time
2. Used full Xpath, Xpath, find by class
3. Tried to locate different elements.
4. Different pages of this.

Referred to various site still couldn't resolve. I am new to python.

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services")
time.sleep(20)
element_text = driver.find_element_by_id("firstheading").text
print(element_text)  ` ---This simplest code is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text **1st T20I (N), Southampton, Sep 4 2020, Australia tour of England** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `class_name` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_class_name("desc").text)
  ```
- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.desc").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='desc text-truncate']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally, to print the `innerText` of an element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CLASS_NAME`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "desc"))).text)
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.desc"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='desc text-truncate']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/19496' \
      '/scorecard/1198235/england-vs-australia-1st-t20i-england-v-australia-2020'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="desc text-truncate"]')
print(element.text)
```

Output:

```
1st T20I (N), Southampton, Sep 4 2020, Australia tour of England
```

Comment: Thank you for the new code. is it possible to explain what is wrong in my code?

Comment: It looks like the Xpath is at fault here. I've tested it and got the same error you had.